# How to find all columns in a database with all NULL values

Tags: sql, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a large Snowflake database with 70+ tables and 3000+ fields.  Is there a query I can use across the entire database to find all columns with all NULLs?  I have a command I can use to find all the columns

```
select * from prod_db.information_schema.columns
```

Is there a way to modify that command to identify which columns are all NULLs?  If there is not a way to do it across the entire database. Is there a way to do it across a table? I do not want to type:

```
select column_name from prod_db.information_schema.table_name
```

3000+ times.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can produce a list of SELECT queries for each column as follows

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ''', TABLE_NAME), ''', '''), COLUMN_NAME), ''', '), 'COUNT(*) FROM '), TABLE_NAME), ' WHERE '), COLUMN_NAME), ' IS NULL OR '), LEN(COLUMN_NAME)), ' = 0'), ' UNION ')
from information_schema.columns
```

2. The result of the above query can then be taken and executed to get the result you need (PS: Remove the UNION on the last row produced from Step 1 before executing)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a SQL generator to generate a SQL statement that will locate columns matching two criteria:

1. The column is in a table with one or more rows
2. The column has all nulls.

To be highly efficient, rather than checking the each table entirely, it uses a UNION ALL block that looks for a single non-null row in each table. It uses `TOP 1` to find a not null row. That way as soon as it finds a not null row, it returns that row and stops scanning that table so it can move to another table scan.

This means that the large UNION ALL section will list tables where it finds a not null row, which is the opposite of what we want. To use this information, a CTE wrapped around the UNION ALL will do an anti-join against the column view in the information schema.

```
with COLS as
(
select    'select top 1 ''' || C.TABLE_CATALOG || ''' as TABLE_CATALOG, ''' || C.TABLE_SCHEMA || 
          ''' as TABLE_SCHEMA, ''' || C.TABLE_NAME || ''' as TABLE_NAME, ''' || C.COLUMN_NAME || 
          ''' as COLUMN_NAME from "' || 
          C.TABLE_CATALOG || '"."' || C.TABLE_SCHEMA || '"."' || C.TABLE_NAME || '"' ||
          ' where "' || C.COLUMN_NAME || '" is not null'
          as NULL_CHECK
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T on
        C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG and
        C.TABLE_SCHEMA  = T.TABLE_SCHEMA  and
        C.TABLE_NAME    = T.TABLE_NAME
where C.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' and T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
      and T.ROW_COUNT > 0
), UNIONED as
(
select listagg(NULL_CHECK, '\nunion all\n') as UNIONED from COLS
)
select replace($$
with NON_NULL_COLUMNS as (
!~UNIONED~!
)
select C.TABLE_CATALOG, C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME, C.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    left join NON_NULL_COLUMNS NN
    on    C.TABLE_CATALOG = NN.TABLE_CATALOG
      and C.TABLE_SCHEMA  = NN.TABLE_SCHEMA
      and C.TABLE_NAME    = NN.TABLE_NAME
      and C.COLUMN_NAME   = NN.COLUMN_NAME
    left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
    on    C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
      and C.TABLE_SCHEMA  = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
      and C.TABLE_NAME    = T.TABLE_NAME
where NN.COLUMN_NAME is null and T.ROW_COUNT > 0
;$$, '!~UNIONED~!', UNIONED) as SQL_TO_RUN from UNIONED
;
```